# Add "preventDefault" to all labels that uses specific Umbraco template

Tags: javascript, jquery, umbraco, preventdefault

I'm having an issue with one of my main templates in umbraco. 
The issue is that, whenever I'm logged in on my website and I hit the 'enter' key whilst focus is on an input label, I'm logged out and redirected to my startpage.

I know that the event.preventDefault() method will stop this, but I cannot figure out how to apply it in my scenario.

Is it possible to add a script to my Umbraco template that adds the "preventDefault()" in case of keyCode == 13 (the enter key)? And if so, how exactly?

I have a bunch of labels in all kinds of macros that uses this template, and I would very much prefer not to add these lines manually for each of them!

I have tried quite a lot of variation of the following, but without any luck:

```
  $("input").click(function(e)
  {
    if(e.keyCode == 13) {

    preventDefault();
    }
  });
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You check the keyCode on a `click`, that won't work. Also, the `preventDefault()` should be used on the event: `e.preventDefault()`.

Use this instead for global enter key:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).keydown(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13) {
      event.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: returning `false` will tell jQuery to prevent the default behaviour & stop propagating the event. No need to `return false` or no need to call `.preventDefault()`

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you! 

However, I can see that this also affects the search functions on my site, so I can no longer search by hitting enter, instead I need to press the button with the mouse now. 

Is there any smart way around this, in these specific scenarios?

Comment: - It also disables use of enter key in multi-line input labels. 
Guess the solution I'm looking for doesn't exist, seeing since I want this applied to some, but not all elements.

Comment: @Jellezilla I think you can also target just the input fields you want. Instead of `$(window)` use `$("#theTargetScopeId input").keypress(...`